# Spree / Solidus remove state from addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, solidus

By default addresses in Spree and Solidus expect a state in the address. In the UK we do not use states. For countries without a state how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Spree and Solidus uses a configuration file which allows you to ignore the state.

1. config/initializers/spree.rb

   ```
   Spree.config do |config|
     config.address_requires_state = false
   end
   ```
2. Restart the webserver

#### Further Reading

[Spree Preferences Documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/preferences.html#spree-configuration-options)